# Test simple logger functions with full code coverage

Tags: javascript, chai, sinon

I'm using Chai, Sinon and Instanbul to test a NodeJS application. Here's the `Logger` code:

```
import Debug, { IDebugger } from 'debug';

export default class Logger {
  private readonly dbg: IDebugger;

  constructor(name: string) {
    this.dbg = Debug(name);
  }

  public log(str: string): void {
    this.dbg(str);
  }
}
```

Here's the test that I have built to start with:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import Logger from '../../src/utils/Logger';
import Debug from 'debug';

describe('Unit tests for Logger class', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });

  describe('#constructor', () => {
    it('should set logger', () => {
      const setLoggerStub = sinon.stub(Logger.prototype, 'log');
      const logExample: string = 'test logger'
      const logger = new Logger(logExample);
      logger.log('test logger')

      sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(setLoggerStub, logExample);
    });
  });
});
```

The code coverage report is the following:
[image]

I'm not sure why the `log` function is not tested, how can I test it and separate the test for the constructor and the test for the `log` function?

I'm not sure about what to test because the only function of `log` is to pass a string to the `debug` library. What should be the approach in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`log` isn't covered because it *never got called*, you stubbed it out with `sinon.stub(Logger.prototype, 'log')`.

Your current implementation is difficult to test because `Logger` is too coupled to `Debug`. Creating instances of dependencies in the constructor is generally not a good idea.

If you invert the dependency, making `Logger`'s constructor take an `IDebugger` instead of the `string` name:

```
import Debug, { IDebugger } from 'debug';

export default class Logger {

  constructor(private readonly dbg: IDebugger) {}

  public log(str: string): void {
    this.dbg(str);
  }
}
```

then when you test `Logger`, you can easily inject a test double:

```
it("debugs the input", () => {
  const debug = sinon.stub();
  const logger = new Logger(debug);
  const message = "hello, world!";

  logger.log(message);

  sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(debug, message);
});
```

This means you don't need to spy on any part of `Logger` itself, allowing you to refactor inside that class more easily. The `Logger` class now only depends on the abstract `IDebugger` interface, not the concrete `Debug` implementation.

Creating a `Logger` instance with a `Debug` given the specific name can just be a function, or a static method:

```
export default class Logger {

  static withName(name: string) {
    return new Logger(Debug(name));
  }

  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Hello, I get the error "logger is not a function", am I missing something?

Comment: @ste missed a `.log`, fixed now. I fixed the stub name in the assertion too.